# Task Management Tracker

Tags: sql-server, schema

[image]

I have this as my proposed structure for task management module I had been working on. I think I can pull off viewing projects I create with the above schema, however I do want to add the ability to assign tasks to other user accounts[table has user_id as PK]. I am seeking some advice as to how to move forward from here to add that ability to assign tasks to users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be a many-to-many relationship between tasks and users, so you will need a table, perhaps ASSIGNED_TASK, that will have FK to the user and task tables. You will likely have some attributes, e.g. user role (task lead, minion, etc), due date, etc.

I recommend that you make your status columns be a string. Using opaque integers is nice from a computer science perspective, but humans find them annoying.

The updated column can be problematic in its meaning. Often the updated date is actually a property of the event (task completion, change in requirements, etc). I recommend that updated be removed from project and task and you track the date of the action in a child table.

Finally, I recommend that your table names be singular not plural. The name of the table should reflect what is being stored in a row and it is independent of whether the table has 0, 1, or a million rows.

Comment: I take your recommendations, I wasn't too far off then. I would want some more tips on creating an action table of events however.

Comment: The table of events is not something special and should be based on what you want to track. For example, task completion date in the task table. If you want to track edits, you could have a project_edit_log table. Write down what facts/actions/events you want to track and then group them logically.

Comment: I see, I think I could whip something up for that. I was thinking that was some sort of standard for databases. I will add the relationship for users + tasks, I could add more data to this join table also would that be a good convention?

Comment: Try to group related facts into tables. Test your design by constructing the SQL statements. All this can be done on paper. I like to maximize the use of the DBMS and minimize managing data in the application.

Comment: I like that approach, so everything is already set up to be queried and presented to user. is it normal practice to add further properties to the joiner table?

Comment: Adding related facts to the link (or joiner) table is appropriate.